# Slow acceleration

Tags: automatic-transmission, vibration, noise

I have a Toyota Corolla that hesitates when accelerating from a stop point, ie from 0-20kmph. Then, speed is normal above 20kmph.

A description of the sound would be: engine rises and so does the RPM(4k-5k) but the car is accelerating slowly until the speed reaches 20kmph. Then, the engine sound drops and so does the RPM(1). Then, the car would be accelerating fine above 20kmph.

Any ideas?????

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: check your transmission fluid.  You should not drive it like that, you will do serious damage quickly.

Comment: I recently changed my fluids but still have the same problem.

Comment: Do you feel / hear the car shifting? Do you know if it's a CVT? 
I have the feeling it might be in limp mode. Meaning it will stay in one gear (usually 3 or 4). Obviously accelerating from 0 in 3rd/4th gear will take long.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the clutches are slipping. Once it shifts into a clutch that holds better, then the engine sounds normal. You should check the fluid. First look at the level, but also the color and smell. The color should be cherry red. The darker it is, the worse off the transmission is. If it smells burnt, then you have problems. Look for one more thing. If you can see black, sooty residue in the fluid on the stick, then you have a burnt clutch.